# Duplicated Data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am using this code here to retrieve data from Firestore. The data is in a `Map` and here is the picture of my Firestore.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

And here is my code when I retrieve from Firestore

```
Future <void> getRoute() async{
  Firestore.instance.collection('routes').snapshots().listen((RouteData) {
    if(RouteData.documents.isNotEmpty){
      for (int i = 0; i < RouteData.documents.length; i++){
        _getPolyline(RouteData.documents[i].data, RouteData.documents[i].documentID);
      }
    }
  });
  setState(() {
  });
}

void _getPolyline(info, infoID) async{
      print(info);}
```

When Im printing the `info` it will display the data many times.

[image: result]
here is the result. As you can see it starts off in `test` then `test1` then `test` again and repeated for some time. Is there something wrong with my code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setState` will trigger a rebuild of your widget. What i think is happening is that when `getRoute()` u are also triggering your build function which will trigger `getRoute()`  to run again.

solution:
make sure your function is not being triggered during a build. you can do this by triggering your function only once in `initState`

Either that or because u are using `snapshots().listen`. this will listen to any changes that happen on that collection.

solution:
use `.get()` instead of `.listen()`

> To read a collection or document once, call the Query.get or DocumentReference.get methods. In the below example a FutureBuilder is used to help manage the state of the request:
> https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read

Comment: Deleting the `setState` solve my issue. Now I have better understanding of it. Thank you.