# Adding New Data in Flutter using Firestore, Result in Redundant Data?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to get data from firestore using class defined like this one:

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getPubs() async {
    queryPubs = await pubsDb.get();
    if (queryPubs!.docs.isEmpty) {
      log("[getPubs] Variable queryPubs is empty");
    } else {
      await pubData(queryPubs!.docs).then((value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          isPub.value = true;
          log("[getPubs] Variable pubAll is not empty");
        } else {
          log("[getPubs] Variable pubAll is empty");
        }
      });
    }
    return queryPubs!;
  }
  
    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> pubData(List<DocumentSnapshot>? docs) async {
for (int i = 0; i < docs!.length; i++) {
  DbPublisher dbPublisher = DbPublisher.fstoreInfo(docs[i]);
  final imgUrl = await getImgUrl(dbPublisher.imgName, DataType.PUBLISHER);
  pubInfo = {
    "name": dbPublisher.name,
    "imgURL": imgUrl,
    "imgName": dbPublisher.imgName,
    "desc": dbPublisher.desc,
    "email": dbPublisher.email,
    "active": dbPublisher.active,
    "status": dbPublisher.status,
    "albums": dbPublisher.albums,
    "songs": dbPublisher.songs,
    "state": dbPublisher.state,
    "privilege": dbPublisher.privilege,
    "payout": dbPublisher.payout,
    "compensation": dbPublisher.compensation,
    "started": dbPublisher.started,
    "due": dbPublisher.due,
    "license": dbPublisher.license,
    "duration": dbPublisher.duration,
    "valid": dbPublisher.valid,
  };
  pubAll!.add(pubInfo);
}
return pubAll!;
```

}

I get the data, but when I was about to add one more data; the new data doesn't get displayed. Instead, it was previous data and there were redundant of that. I used the latest package of firestore. Did someone ever experience this one? I used GetX dependency injection for all of this. I used GetxService as it made it as permanent.

Update: redundant here I meant there is the same data over and over. But when I restarted the app, all the data return normal as it used to be. I wonder what is going on?

Update:
The flutter code

```js
Expanded(
  child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    future: dNd.getPubs(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
        listAlbs = snapshot.data!.docs;
        if (listAlbs.isNotEmpty) {
          totalAlbs = listAlbs.length;
          log("Load $totalAlbs albums from Firestore");
          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
            controller: scrollCtrl,
            itemCount: listAlbs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return albsFstore(context, dNd.pubAll![index], index);
            },
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(child: FavText("The album data is empty", 15.0));
        }
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const Center(child: FavText("The server is error", 15.0));
      } else {
        return const Center(child: FavText("The data is empty", 15.0));
      }
    } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
     return AlignPositioned(
      dx: 0,
      dy: -(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
      child: Container(
        width: 128,
        height: 128,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(borderRadius:     
        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0)), color: Color.fromARGB(88, 44, 44, 44)),
        child: const LoadingIndicator(indicatorType: Indicator.ballRotateChase, colors: rainbowColors),),);
    }
    return const SizedBox();
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: Maybe this is because I set persistence as true? I will come back after investigation.

Comment: Nah, the data is not updated only after I restarted the app. This is weird.

Comment: so were you able to fix this as per your comment above.

Comment: Just updated the question with Flutter code inside. Could you help me out for this @VaidehiJamankar???

Comment: Or do you want to be contributor of my project? I will add you if you have github account? You will get paid of course. @VaidehiJamankar???

Comment: I recommend you should check these examples once to see if they help 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68872267/duplicated-data-from-firestore and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130316/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-in-flutter.
Also go through this useful document for onetime read implementation
  https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read

Comment: Okay, noted. Now I have gotten where I went wrong. I will fix this asap. I have to use another trick to download url image, and that is where I went wrong. I should have used firebase storage for this and saved it along with another firestore data all and at once.

Comment: Wege, was the information in answer below helpful , do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore gives you the ability to read the value of a collection or a document. This can be a one-time read, or provided by real time updates when the data within a query changes.
For basic write operations, you can use `set()` to save data to a specified reference, replacing any existing data at that path and to read a collection or document once, call the Query.get or DocumentReference.get methods.

As recommended in comments, you should check these examples once [Duplicate Data from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68872267/duplicated-data-from-firestore)and [How to get data from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130316/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-in-flutter).
Also go through this useful document for [one time read implementation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read).